# Condicional OR en un WHERE

Tags: sql

tengo un pequeño problema al hacer una consulta SQL

```
                SELECT T1.FechaFactura
                FROM Tabla1 T1
                INNER JOIN Tabla2 T2
                    ON  T1.des = T2.Relacionado WHERE 
                    T2.Uuid=@pUUID
                    AND T1.proveedor=@pnumproveedor
                    AND importe>0
                    AND T2.UUID IS NOT NULL
                    AND B.antiguo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3'
```

Mi problema es con los WHERE, necesito que se cumplan las condiciones de los WHERE, pero en el ultimo condicional "and B.antitugo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3'
Necesito que se si no se cumple que B.antiguo is null entonces evalue que B.estatus  = '3'
Pero a como tengo el query lo que hace es que al llegar al OR pareciera que solo evalua que si B.estatus es igual a 3, ignora las demás condiciones de el WHERE mas de arriba, como puedo hacer para que no suceda así? que se cumplan las condiciones de el WHERE de arriba,y en el ultimo se cumpla la condicion de el OR

Answer (score 1):

Pon esa condición entre paréntesis, eso crea una agrupación y primero se evaluará lo que esté adentro y ese resultado será evaluado con el AND de afuera:

```
SELECT T1.FechaFactura
    FROM Tabla1 T1
    INNER JOIN Tabla2 T2
    ON  T1.des = T2.Relacionado 
    WHERE 
    T2.Uuid=@pUUID
    AND T1.proveedor=@pnumproveedor
    AND importe>0
    AND T2.UUID IS NOT NULL
    AND (B.antiguo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3')
```